# How can I convert a datetime variable into a date and time separated variables?

Tags: sql, automation, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I would like to Convert a DateTime variable into a date and time separated variable. I have tried with this SQL query but it doesn't work.

[image: SQL used]

Comment: Your question is tagged MySQL, but the code is definitely not MySQL -- and not syntactically correct at all ( the parentheses don't balance).  I'm really confused.  Also, sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [query](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query) tags.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database is sql server, and not mysql, you can get these 2 values with a query like this:

```
select
  convert(date, dateTimeDepartureOutbound__c) as thedate,
  convert(time, dateTimeDepartureOutbound__c) as thetime
from Order_DE
```

If you really were with mysql, one option could be this one:

```
select
  date(dateTimeDepartureOutbound__c) as thedate,
  time(dateTimeDepartureOutbound__c) as thetime
from Order_DE
```

Comment: Hi @Jaime, thanks a lot for the explanation. It's an SQL server but when I validate this code it shows this error: "An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Only SELECT queries are valid. Select must be the first word of the query. Order_DE is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views." but the Order DE does exist so I don't really understand what the problem is

Comment: Hi @Lorenzo. Neither do I... `Order_DE` is the table you used in your example. And as the error says, `SELECT` must be the first word of you query.

Comment: I have removed the `WITH` if you were confusing with it...

Comment: Thanks a lot @jaime, but the error still remains but I don't understand why. Errors: Order_DE is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views. The data extension name is Order DE so I don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: try searching in you `information_schema` where your `Order` table is... and what's its real name `select * from information_schema.tables where upper(table_name) like 'ORDER%'`

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server

select CAST(<your_date_time> AS DATE), CAST(<your_date_time> as TIME)